# images with radio buttons in a list display diagonally

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to get all images to be in a horizontal scroller with radio button (preferably) under the images. I keep running into a problem where the next image wants to start at the bottom of a radio button.

an example of the problem with the code, http://jsfiddle.net/zVrq8/

I don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: Can you update your example to include actual images? Use http://dummyimage.com/. It's rather confusing to figure out what you actually want at the moment. In your demo you have `div#lasteventimg img {
    width: 200x; }` - do you mean `px`? Or should that `width` property be taken out completely because it's not doing anything because there's an invalid value? *confusing!*

Comment: sure! I updated it to fix the issues you addressed, I removed the entire lasteventimg img as well in order to more precisely demonstrate the problem

Comment: Could you provide the link to your updated version?

Comment: doh!, http://jsfiddle.net/mMH7b/ The problem now is I cannot get rid of extra white space im my scrolling window. I'd like it to scroll only to the end of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it for the first two items. For the rest it's the same: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zVrq8/6/)

What I did, added a `float: left` to the `li`:

```
div#lasteventimg ul li{ 
    float:left;
}
```

this way `li` will go next to the previous `li`, as long as there is space in the `ul`

Second thing I changed is in the HTML, added to a single `li` both the image and the input, also a `<br />` to make the input below the image. There are other ways to do this, but this seemed the easiest here.

Comment: That solves the diagonal problem, thank you. But I introduced another problem by trying to make ul width:auto with white-space: nowrap. The formatting gets all thrown off. Example at http://jsfiddle.net/CQGNw/

Comment: that's because the ul's "auto width" follows it's parent's width if its too large to fit, and it's parent's width is 20%, so it becomes the ul's width, that's why its messed up

Comment: I'm hoping to create a scroller that is perhaps 80% of the page width with many images inside.